# Reading from a file using a Scanner Class in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to read from a file and pass the output as tokens to a HashMap object. Seems like my program cant seem to find the file. Here's the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {
            HashMap<String, Integer> map = sortingFromAFile("file.rtf");
            System.out.println(map);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HashMap sortingFromAFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        Integer count = 1;

        File file = new File(fileName);

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                if (map.containsKey(sc.nextLine())){
                    count+= map.get(sc.nextLine());
                }
                map.put(sc.nextLine(), count);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return map;
    }
```

The file that I'm trying to read is in the root of the project directory.

Here's the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at com.soumasish.Main.sortingFromAFile(Main.java:38)
    at com.soumasish.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Any help please.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger? That's where I would start. See what is inside `sc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you call `sc.nextLine()` you read another line. So on the first iteration through the loop, `if(map.containsKey(sc.nextLine()))` reads the first line, and checks whether it's in the map. `count += map.get(sc.nextLine())` reads the *second* line, gets that value from the map and adds it to the count. `map.put(sc.nextLine(), count)` reads the *third* line and stores the count there. If there are more than three lines, the loop then runs again, and reads the 4th/5th/6th lines.

You need to use a variable to store the current line, since you can only read each line once:

```
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            if (map.containsKey(line)){
                count+= map.get(line);
            }
            map.put(line, count);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but ended up getting a whole host of formatting info.
 {=1, \pard\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\pardirnatural=1, {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1343\cocoasubrtf160=1, \margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0=1, {\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}=1, \f0\fs24 \cf0 How can I just read the text.

Comment: @Clockwork That's because that stuff is what's in your file. Save the file as plain text, in the program you made it in, to remove formatting information. Useful debugging tip: Notepad shows a file exactly as it's stored. You probably want to be using Notepad or a similar program to work with plain text files on Windows, as it doesn't have formatting.